# Category template Wordpress

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I want display each category by template, for example display the **category 1** with ***template 2 columns*** and the **category 2** with template ***3 columns***.
I can use  [Category template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates) , but with this method I must know the slug or the ID of each category. and in my case I'm trying the create a template for a client, and I will not know what  categories he will create, so how can I give  for my client a choice about choosing the template for his each category ? Thanks.

Comment: if you don't know the category id, how would you know if he wants a 2 column template or a 3 column template?

Comment: @alexalex : I think you don't understand my question, or I didn't explain well my question :)
I asked: how can I give for my client a choice about choosing the template for his each category 
for me I don't know what categories he has.
Thanks.

Comment: you can do it by providing interface to your client where he can choose template for each category .